# Python 3 - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a python 2 script to python 3, here's the script:

```
def encode(key, clear):
    enc = []
    for i in range(len(clear)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        enc_c = chr(ord(clear[i] + key_c) % 256)
        enc.append(enc_c)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode("".join(enc))

def decode(key, enc):
    dec = []
    enc = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc)
    for i in range(len(enc)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        dec_c = chr((256 + enc[i] - key_c) % 256)
        dec.append(dec_c)
    return "".join(dec)
```

When I run that, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):              
  File "./script", line 132, in <module>         
    payload=decode(p,payload)                   
  File "./script", line 22, in decode            
    dec_c = chr((256 + enc[i] - key_c) % 256)   
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

How should I fix this ? Sorry I'm new to python.

Comment: you can try with `dec_c = chr((256 + int(enc[i]) - key_c) % 256)`

Answer (score 0):

From [Beginner's Python tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner's_Python_Tutorial/Exception_Handling)

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
>
> What Python is trying to tell you (but struggling to find a good word
>   for it) is that you can't join a string of letters and a number into
>   one string of text.

to avoid it you can do this you can either convert `enc[i]` and `key_c` to `int` `dec_c = chr((256 + int(enc[i]) - int(key_c)) % 256)`.

or convert 256 to `str` then the whole expresison back to `int` so it can be modulo by 256 `dec_c = chr(int((str(256) + enc[i] - key_c)) % 256)`

Note this might not be the result you want. However, you can fix the error this way